# What is the idea behind required tags here on Meta?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta-tags, required-tags

Why are there required tags? ([discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion), [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) , [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request), [support](/questions/tagged/support))

Why must I choose one of those tags every time I want to post a question?

Comment: Because the question asked will have to fall in at least one of those categories.

Comment: Well if it's not a discussion, bug, support or feature request, what is it?

Comment: And OT, but useful: [How do I participate in Meta Stack Overflow and not die trying?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-stack-overflow-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: its a question with many tags if i want choose , not taht i must use one of those.

Comment: You must choose one of those, because a Meta question will have to be a discussion, feature request, bug report or support question. It's as simple as that.

Comment: ok thx for the answer

Comment: Were you by any chance trying to ask a programming question here on MSO? ;)

Answer (score 8):

It is explained in the [Tour page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tour):

> [image]

Any other question will simply be off topic.